# Biber suddenly stopped working in sharelatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am a biochemistry graduate student writing his M.Sc. thesis using Latex for the first time. I am about to submit my final draft. I was applying some of my supervisor's corrections and adding new references when biblatex/biber stopped working. I tried to remove the new references, but it won't fix the problem.

Has anyone ever experienced it? If necessary, I could give access to sharelatex. I think it's something very silly...

EDIT:
 I checked the log file and it says:

> "Please (re)run Biber on on the file:output and rerun LaTex afterwards"

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Without more info it will be impossible to help. Have you had a look at some of the error files provided. I haven't been on sharelatex lately so I cannot tell you exactly where to look for them.

Comment: You probably cannot paste into the comment. Update your question instead. Remember you can indent pasted code by highlighting it and hitting ctrl-k

Comment: This is then not really a question for this site, but rather a question on how to use the sharelatex site. That information should be available on the sharelatex website.

Comment: And also note your title is wrong as the message indicates that your are using or requesting biber

Comment: Try to add   `backend=biber` to the options of `biblatex` , i.e., you should have something like `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: As it stands, I'm pleased you solved your issue but this won't help anyone else, really, so it's 'unclear'.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up screening my 300+ references block-by-block: there was one white space that caused all the problems! one! I learned significantly today. Thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: Just for the archives. Where do exactly did some whitespace cause all this trouble?

Comment: @daleif Hi! It was a reference's name in the .bib file
I wrote: Canadian Task2001 instead of CanadianTask2001. Somehow, it confused biber...